# Text without wrap in PdfPtable in iText/Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfptable

i have a problem with the PdfPTable in iText (Version 4.2.0). I calculate the maximun width for each column (depends on the entrys on this place). After this i give the method PdfPTable.setWidths() these values.

Now the problem, if i have to many columns that iText must expand these to the second page it's destroy the associated columnswidth on the side (Text would be wrap).

My destination is that the text wouldn't be wrap. the text should be in one line (that's why i calculate the columnwidt).

Above is the code, this works.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PdfTest
{
    public static final String RESULT = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\tableTest.pdf";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        // ---- Test-Entrys ----
        final String[] earningsSpecial =
        {
                "Objectiv-C", "Java", "C#", "C++", "Eclipse", "Stackoverflow", "Netbeans", "BugTracker", "iText", "Table-Test", "Mac OS X", "Linux", "Microsoft", "Android", "News", "About", "iTest", "Create PDF"
        };
        final ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(earningsSpecial);
        // ---------------------

        final Document document = new Document();
        final PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        final Font myFont = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);

        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        Rectangle rec = document.getPageSize();

        final float pageWidth = rec.getWidth();
        final float pageHeight = rec.getHeight();

        // 50 for left, 50 for right
        final float finalPageWidth = pageWidth - 100;
        // just works for the top, bottom is another TODO
        final float finalPageHeight = pageHeight - 50;

        document.open();

        final String[] entriesValueSpace = init(list);

        final HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> tmpCalcList = calculateRowSpans(entriesValueSpace, pageWidth - 100);

        final PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(entriesValueSpace.length);

        table.setWidthPercentage(90);
        table.setTotalWidth(finalPageWidth);

        // This are the calculated column widths (this comes from the method
        // calculateRowSpans). It's only for the test too.
        float[] tmpfloatCalcList =
        {
                56.004005f, 25.344f, 15.336001f, 22.68f, 38.676003f, 74.688f, 51.36f, 62.016003f, 26.004002f, 57.348003f, 54.684002f, 28.68f, 48.672005f, 41.352f, 30.0f, 31.356003f, 26.004002f, 63.348003f
        };

        int[] tmpCalcVerhColumn = new int[tmpfloatCalcList.length];

        // With this i would calculate the proportion of each column to the
        // total pageWidth (not the finalPageWidth (finalPageWidth =
        // pageWidth-100)).
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpfloatCalcList.length; i++)
        {
            tmpCalcVerhColumn[i] = (int) ((tmpfloatCalcList[i] * 100) / pageWidth);
        }

        table.setWidths(tmpCalcVerhColumn);

        for (String[] movie : list)
        {
            for (String string : movie)
            {
                table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, myFont)));
            }
        }

        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

        int tillThenPosition = 0;
        int lastPosition = 0;

        for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> entry : tmpCalcList.entrySet())
        {
            tillThenPosition += entry.getValue().size();
            table.writeSelectedRows(lastPosition, tillThenPosition, 0, -1, 50, finalPageHeight, canvas);
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            document.newPage();
            lastPosition = tillThenPosition;
        }

        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the longest entry from each String [] in the list. With this i
     * prevent a line break in the table.
     * 
     * @param entrys
     * @return
     */
    private String[] init(final ArrayList<String[]> entrys)
    {
        String[] entryLength = null;
        for (String[] earning : entrys)
        {
            if (entryLength == null)
            {
                entryLength = new String[earning.length];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < earning.length; i++)
            {
                if (entryLength[i] == null || entryLength[i].length() < earning[i].length())
                {
                    entryLength[i] = earning[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return entryLength;
    }

    /**
     * This method calculate the span for each column and save it in a map. A
     * map because with this it's possible to know how much sites with
     * associated columnswidth are available.
     * 
     * @param entriesValueSpace
     * @param pageWidth
     * @return
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> calculateRowSpans(final String[] entriesValueSpace, float pageWidth) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> calculatedRowSpan = new HashMap<>();
        float widthPoint;
        float pageWidthCounter = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        ArrayList<Float> sizesPerPage = new ArrayList<>();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();

        for (String entry : entriesValueSpace)
        {
            widthPoint = bf.getWidthPoint(entry, 12);
            sizesPerPage.add(widthPoint);
            pageWidthCounter += widthPoint;

            if (pageWidthCounter > pageWidth - 100)
            {
                calculatedRowSpan.put(counter, sizesPerPage);
                counter++;
                pageWidthCounter = 0;
                sizesPerPage = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }

        calculatedRowSpan.put(counter, sizesPerPage);

        return calculatedRowSpan;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        new PdfTest().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions whould be nice, thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I see my name in your code, which means you shouldn't expect support as you're using a version of iTextSharp that is obsolete. (2) You say that your code works, so I wonder: what is your actual question?

Comment: i won't text wrapping. if i get more columns, the text wraps, i'm wondering about that beecause i calculate the column width and if i have columns for only 1 page it works fine.